# SQL CSV import need to read multiple sets

Tags: csv, stored-procedures, import, sql-server-2012

i am having an issue i am trying to bring in a csv file, but i need to read the 2nd line to get the report filter and then the actual data starts on line 5.  example of data

Line 1:  Report Date

Line 2:  Storage #1

Line 3:  blank

Line 4(header row):  Pallet, Space, Quantity, perishable,etc

Line 5:  1,10,500,No,this is a test

i can bring in the file data, if i tell it firstrow = 5, but i don't get the filter , if i remove that line it doesn't think its a csv and runs it all as one column and thats it or would it be better to just basically dump the text to a single field and then parse it out from there.?

Please advise

thanks

Comment: By what method are you trying to import this? Is this SQL Server? Please tag the target database.

Comment: Perform 2 read. Read first without field terminator to get 2nd line. Second as CSV

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.